# Call a function from baseActivity android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an activity BaseActivity. BaseActivity has a broadcast set as

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceivedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            mDialog.dismiss();
            if (Constants.ACTION_REQUEST_QUOTE.equals(action)) 
            {
                requestQuoteViewer();
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (Constants.ACTION_PUSH.equals(action))
            {
               // CALL A FUNCTION IN MYACTIVITY
            }
        }
    };
```

Now I have many activities e.g MyActivity extends BaseActivity
On broadcast receive, i want to call a function defined in MyActivity (mainly UI Changes). How can I call a function in MyActivity from BaseActivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a method abstract in the base class and implement it in the derived class (MainActivity).

add abstract modifier to your BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity
```

Create an abstract method in your base activity

```
public abstract void test();
```

then, override it in the derived activity (Main Activity).

```
@Override
public void test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

In your base activity you can call it normally.

```
test();
```

> Now, you will have multiple implementations on test method based on
>   the Activity that is running now. Each implementation will function
>   differently corresponding to the running activity.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I guess best way is to use interface that your base Activity implements and when you need to change its behavior for some activity simple override the same in that activity.